# Cordova 2.1.0 under XCode: Cordova/CDVViewController.h file not found

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, ipad

i´ve received the aforementioned Error.

At the Moment, i try to learn Phonegap by means of the Book of Andrew Lunny - Beginners Guide. He describes everything by means of examples and little Applications. In the first 3 Chapter everything works perfectly but now i receive this Error, after i create a new Project!

Could anyone tell me, what to do at this point? I search about this Error, but without any success.

I try to update Cordova to Version 2.1.0, but i have still the same error..

I use xCode 4.4 and Phonegap 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the missing CordovaLib.xcodeproj! I drag&drop it from my explorer (Users/{your username}/Documents/PhoneGap/CordovaLib/), where the CordovaLib.xcodeproj is saved, to the xcode package explorer!